# Is success part compulsory in ajax?

Tags: ajax

In all example, answer, question I see that in ajax part there a section `success`. What is the benefit of this? Should I add this? Is it compulsory?

Comment: `ajax` is not a particular implementation but a general purpose technology. Check the corresponding library documentation to see if it's required and what it is for.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the jQuery ajax library, you can have a look at the API docs here, https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/
It is an optional event handler function. It could be useful for logging a successful response, or initiating another event upon successful completion of your ajax call.